# JRI library(fgarch) not working

Tags: java, r, jri

I am new to R and trying to load fgarch library using JRI REngine. 
Following is the code that I used.

```
rEngine.eval("addpkg('fgarch', 3010.82 )");
rEngine.eval("library(\"fgarch\")");
rEngine.assign("r", returns);    
REXP result = rEngine.eval("garchFit(r)"):
```

result is coming up as null.
I tried with other libraries for ex: stringr but still getting same.

Could some one please help me how to load libraries using JRI REngine